# Can a Promise be passed as an attribute of a Lightning Component application event?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, promises

I am attempting (but failing - getting undefined when the event is handled) to pass a [Promise](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_promises.htm) returned by a `lightning:workspaceAPI` [getEnclosingTabId](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_lightning_getEnclosingTabId.htm) call as an attribute of an application event.

Do you expect this to work and its just a bug in my code?

Comment: You can't pass any sort of function through an event. I'm not sure this is in the docs, but I remember experimenting with function references with a similar result. Just can't be done.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes that is what I'm seeing. Just makes working with a promise API clumsy (even for my simple case) in that the event firing code has to fire the event only when the promise has resolved.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've done some more changes/debugging and it looks a promise can be passed in the event. The  Lightning inspector shows it as an empty object but seems to be working.

Comment: Well, if it works, you should answer your question. Inquiring minds need to know.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes I will when I'm sure. Will check more carefully first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is *yes a Promise can be passed in an event* based on this code working:

```
accept : function(component, event, action) {
    var cId = component.get("v.instanceId");
    var eId = event.getParams().instanceId;
    if (cId && eId) {
        Promise.all([cId, eId]).then($A.getCallback(function(ids) {
            if (ids[0] === ids[1]) action();
        })).catch($A.getCallback(function(err) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + err);
        }));
    }
},
```

This code is comparing an `aura:attribute` that is a Promise with an event attribute that is a promise.

Thanks to this important point [Promise and access to access=private attributes](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204437/promise-and-access-to-access-private-attributes) I now have the `$A.getCallback` in there too.